# Maximum number of cells in arrangement of $d$ polytopes?

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

An arrangement of polytopes (analogous to an arrangement of hyperplanes) $\mathcal{P}$ is just a set of polytopes in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Suppose $|\mathcal{P}| = n$.

Then a cell is a connected component of $\mathbb{R^d} \setminus \bigcup_{p \in \mathcal{P}} p$. What is the maximum number of cells in an arrangement of polytopes?

I know that the maximum number of cells in an arrangement of $n$ hyperplanes in $\mathbb{R}^d$ is $\phi_d(n) := \sum_{k=0}^d \binom{n}{d}$ if $d < n$ and $2^n$ o.w. . Is there something similar for arrangements of polytopes?

Comment: What is *your* definition of a polytope ?

Comment: convex hull of some finite number of points.

Comment: Do you bound by some integer $p$ this number of points ?

Comment: Ok if that parameter is needed.

Comment: If you don't bound this number : the answer for the maximum is $\infty$.